# The fundamental group of complex plane with $n$ secants

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm studying how to calculate fundamental group.Here is a interesting problems I can't handle it.

Setting $l_{1}$,$l_{2}$,$\cdots$,$l_{n}$ are n line segments of complex plane $\mathbb{C}$(including endpoints),they are disjoint.
The endpoints of $l_{i}$ correspond to complex number $a_{2i-1}$ and $a_{2i}$($i=1,2,\cdots,n$).Setting $X=\mathbb{C}-\cup^{n}_{i=1}l_{i}$.

I want to calculate $\pi_{1}(X)$, but I have no idea.

Comment: Observe that $\mathbb{C} - \{a_{2i-1}, i =1,2,\ldots,n \}$ deformation retracts to $X$.